# Create layers of confirmed and unconfirmed alerts using select

Tags: google-earth-engine, java, select

I aim to create one layer with confirmed alerts + Date and one layer with confirmed alerts +Date from a dataset in GEE.
The dataset has two bands: 'Alert' and 'Date'.

Confirmed alerts are 2, while unconfirmed are 3.
However, when I try to select the alerts it tells me that my line is not a function.

What am I doing wrong?

```
//Citation: Reiche et al. (2021): Forest disturbance alerts for the Congo Basin using Sentinel-1, ERL.
//adapt RADD alerts to use as input for prioirtization 
var radd = ee.ImageCollection('projects/radar-wur/raddalert/v1');
print(radd)

//create one layer with confirmed and unconfirmed alerts 
//confirmed = 2, unconfirmed = 3
var confirmed_radd = radd.select('Alert').eq(2)
var unconfirmed_radd = radd.select('Alert').eq(3)

print(confirmed_radd)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`radd` is an [`ee.imageCollection()`](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-imagecollection) and [`select()`](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-image-select) is a method of [`ee.image()`](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-image)

Here I get the first image of the collection and select from the `Alert` property. You will probably want to use a different method to reduce your collection to an image, depending on your workflow (perhaps by filtering a particular date).

```js
var radd = ee.ImageCollection('projects/radar-wur/raddalert/v1');

// get the first image from the collection and use `select`
var confirmed_radd = radd.first().select('Alert').eq(2)   
var unconfirmed_radd = radd.first().select('Alert').eq(3)

print(confirmed_radd)
```

To apply the filter on all images in the collection, first define a function and then map over the imageCollection.

However, I noticed that not all of the images have the 'Alert' band as some are the baseline data for the year. Therefore, you have to do a bit of fiddling to map over the collection.

Here I make a function that first checks if the Alert band exists, if it does, to get the pixels with value 2, otherwise to set a new property that can be filtered afterwards.

```js
var radd = ee.ImageCollection('projects/radar-wur/raddalert/v1');

print(radd);

var filterConfirmed = function(image){
  // get properties to copy over to output image
  var properties = image.propertyNames();
  
  // check if the 'Alert' property exists, if so, filter the confirmed alerts, if not set a new property called isBaseline
  var outImg = ee.Image(ee.Algorithms.If(

    // condition to check
    ee.List(image.bandNames()).contains('Alert'),     

    // do if true
    image.updateMask(image.select('Alert').eq(2))        // mask out pixels that are not Alert=2 
         .copyProperties(image, properties),

    // do if false
    ee.Image(0).set('isBaseline', 'baseline')));      
    
    return outImg;
  
};

// map over original collection and select the confirmed alerts (if band exists)
var raddConfirmedCollection = radd.map(filterConfirmed);

// remove images that have the 'isBaseline' property
var raddConfirmedCollection = raddConfirmedCollection.filter(ee.Filter.neq('isBaseline', 'baseline'));


// make 'cividis' colour ramp (dark blue to bright yellow)
var palette = ['00204d', '414d6b', '7d7c78', 'beaf6f', 'ffea46'];

// add collection to map
Map.addLayer(raddConfirmedCollection, {bands:['Date'], palette:palette, min:20000, max:22085});    // the min and max values I chose here represent the beginning of year 2020 to about now.

// print to console for inspection
print(raddConfirmedCollection);
```

In the visualisation, the dark blue pixels are oldest, and bright yellow are newest.

[image]

Comment: thank you for your help!

Comment: Do you know how I could select both bands ('Alert') and ('Date')?

Comment: See my updated answer. I create a mask to get the Alert=2 pixels and then select the Date band. Please update your question to specifiy getting the Date band, else it may be confusing for future readers. You can of course skip the selection of the Date band and keep them all, and only mask the pixels based on the Alert value.

Comment: thank you so much for your quick answer! However, now once i print the outcome, i only have the band 'date' left.  I am looking for a way of selecting both bands.

Comment: As I mention in my previous comment, you can skip the `.select()`. I have removed it from my answer.

Comment: Amazing, thanks so much!